# What is $v$ in conformal field theory?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, spin-chains

In reading about conformal field theory applied to spin chains of length $N$, I've seen the following expression several times, describing how the central charge $c$ can be extracted from the ground state energy:

$$E(N) = eN - \frac{\pi v}{6 N} c + o\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)$$

Here, $e$ is a constant giving the energy density at large $N$. Note that one can fit this ansatz to deduce the coefficient of the $\frac{1}{N}$ term, and hence extract the central charge $c$.

However, to extract the central charge requires knowing the value of $v$, which I'm having trouble interpreting. Naively, I expect that there's a sense in which excitations give an energy $E(p) = E(0) + v |p-p_0|$ where $E(0)$ is the ground state energy and $p_0$ is the ground state momentum, since $v$ has been called the sound velocity in one of the references I read. Is this indeed the case, and how is $v$ numerically extracted in practice?

---

Here are some of the references discussing $v$. In ["Antiferromagnetic Ising chain in a mixed transverse and longitudinal magnetic field"](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0306468), the ansatz above was used to extract $c=1/2$ on an Ising critical line on page 10:

[image: Ising Page 10]

Similarly, in ["Entanglement entropy scaling of the XXZ chain"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.5828), the ansatz above was used to extract $c=1$ in the critical phase of the $XXZ$ chain (though with some finite-size deviations near the $SU(2)$ invariant point) on page 9:

[image: XXZ page 9]

and page 10:

[image: XXZ page 10]

The forms of $v(N)$ in both of these papers point towards $v$ being defined through a dispersion relation $v |p|$, but there is a little tension with my exact form above, as the Ising model paper above considers the dispersion near $p=\pi$ even though the ground state is at $p=0$.

---

Edit: To make this more concrete, I numerically looked at the dispersion relation for the antiferromagnetic transverse field ising chain of $L=18$. Here are the results below in blue solid lines; I superimpose a linear dispersion relation with $v=1/2$ (as noted in the first reference) centered around $p=0$ and $p=\pi$. The linear dispersion relation is dotted and I take it's lowest energy to be the ground state energy (i.e. the energy at $p=0$).

The numerically-found dispersion relation is nonlinear, but it looks close to linear around $p=0$ and $p=\pi$. However, there's a kink in the dispersion for $p=0$ that is smoothed out in $p=\pi$, seemingly making the latter a better candidate for extracting the slope. However, I find that $p=\pi$ has an energy just slightly higher than $p=0$, so I find it curious that it has a dispersion relation that's more linear.

[image: Dispersion centered at p=0]

[image: Dispersion centered at p=pi]

Comment: You will need some way of fitting which allows to eliminate $v$ (unless you know something about the way you put the CFT on a lattice -- but then you already know $c$, presumably).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thanks. I'm a bit inexperienced in CFT; my guess was that through ground state energy as a function of $L$, one can extract $vc$, while one could potentially extract $v$ directly by comparing the ground state energies in different momenta sectors. However, it wasn't clear to me which sectors to investigate in, or whether this is true generally. Do you have a sense for which quantities can be used to extract $v$ alone?

Comment: The last text you quote explains how to extract $v$: It is the slope of the E(k) curve.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch The trouble for me is that it seems a little arbitrary in those references where the slope is extracted, $k=0$ or $k=\pi$; in the ising model, $k=\pi$ is used despite that not being the sector containing the absolute ground state, and I haven't yet checked whether the $XXZ$ model has its ground state at $k=0$. I was thinking that the dispersion would only be linear near the ground state, and that it may have some curvature at momenta far from the ground state momentum, but probably I should check that.

Comment: Well, if it is a CFT, the slope should be the same everywhere -- the dispersion is linear. In practice, you will probably indeed want to work close to the ground state.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thanks again. I checked the dispersion numerically at a finite size; added the figures to the question. It's somewhat different than I expected - it's fairly nonlinear, but looks linear about $p=0$ and $p=\pi$, and looks more linear for $p=\pi$ despite that momentum having a slightly higher energy than $p=0$. If I have time I'll check some other sizes to see if the $p=0$ part straightens out. However, I'm getting more convinced that we can fit around either $0$ or $\pi$, so long as one fits to a few points instead of extracting the slope via adjacent points.